# Customization with PostingsSolrHighlighter

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solr-highlight

I'm using PostingsSolrHighlighter, with default params, and it seems to be giving good results. My use case is to search text paragraphs against the full doc and get relevant snippets, and this highlighter does give most close paragraphs from matching documents.

The customization i need is to remove waste snippets which do not seem related to the searched para. At this time, i'm looking to employ a simple method: remove the snippets that have a relative score of 0.5 or less.
But i can't find a way to get the scores Solr computes for the sentences/snippets, so i can discard the less desired ones.

Can i tell solr to keep snippets only when its score is greater than xyz score, or it can give me the snippets score somehow?

I still want to keep the order (according to the start-position of snippets in the original doc) of resultant snippets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i could not get any way to ask Solr to return snippets with scores or discard snippets having score less than certain number, but i extended the highlighter and formatter, and now getting snippet with their scores (solr-computed absolute score & relative score). Below is the extension code if needed by someone:

```
package solrExtension;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.postingshighlight.DefaultPassageFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.postingshighlight.Passage;
import org.apache.lucene.search.postingshighlight.PassageFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.postingshighlight.PostingsHighlighter;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.HighlightParams;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList;
import org.apache.solr.highlight.PostingsSolrHighlighter;
import org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest;
import org.apache.solr.search.DocList;


public class CustomPostingsSolrHighlighter extends PostingsSolrHighlighter {


    protected PostingsHighlighter getHighlighter(SolrQueryRequest req) {
        return new customSolrExtendedPostingsHighlighter(req);
    }

    public class customSolrExtendedPostingsHighlighter extends PostingsSolrHighlighter.SolrExtendedPostingsHighlighter {
        public customSolrExtendedPostingsHighlighter(SolrQueryRequest req) {
            super(req);
        }

        @Override
        protected PassageFormatter getFormatter(String fieldName) {
              String preTag = params.getFieldParam(fieldName, HighlightParams.TAG_PRE, "<em>");
              String postTag = params.getFieldParam(fieldName, HighlightParams.TAG_POST, "</em>");
              String ellipsis = params.getFieldParam(fieldName, HighlightParams.TAG_ELLIPSIS, "... ");
              String encoder = params.getFieldParam(fieldName, HighlightParams.ENCODER, "simple");
              return new CustomPassageFormatter(preTag, postTag, ellipsis, "html".equals(encoder));
        }
    }


    public class CustomPassageFormatter extends DefaultPassageFormatter {
        public CustomPassageFormatter() {
            super();
        }

        public CustomPassageFormatter(String preTag, String postTag,
                String ellipsis, boolean escape) {
            super(preTag, postTag, ellipsis, escape);
        }

        @Override
        public String format(Passage passages[], String content) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int pos = 0;
            double psgTtlScore = 0, maxScore=0, score;
            int psgCounts = 0;
            List<CustomPsg> psgGroups = new ArrayList<CustomPsg>();
            for (Passage passage : passages) {
                // don't add ellipsis if it's the first one, or if it's
                // connected.
                if (passage.getStartOffset() > pos && pos > 0) {
                    score = psgTtlScore / psgCounts;
                    if (score > maxScore)
                        maxScore = score;
                    sb.append("[[").append(score).append("]]");
                    psgGroups.add(new CustomPsg(sb.toString(), score));
                    //sb.append(ellipsis);
                    psgTtlScore = 0;
                    psgCounts = 0;
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                }
                psgTtlScore += passage.getScore();
                psgCounts++;
                pos = passage.getStartOffset();
                for (int i = 0; i < passage.getNumMatches(); i++) {
                    int start = passage.getMatchStarts()[i];
                    int end = passage.getMatchEnds()[i];
                    // it's possible to have overlapping terms
                    if (start > pos) {
                        append(sb, content, pos, start);
                    }
                    if (end > pos) {
                        sb.append(preTag);
                        append(sb, content, Math.max(pos, start), end);
                        sb.append(postTag);
                        pos = end;
                    }
                }
                sb.append("[").append(passage.getScore()).append("]");
                // it's possible a "term" from the analyzer could span a
                // sentence boundary.
                append(sb, content, pos, Math.max(pos, passage.getEndOffset()));
                pos = passage.getEndOffset();
            }
            sb.append("[[").append(psgTtlScore / psgCounts).append("]]");
            psgGroups.add(new CustomPsg(sb.toString(), psgTtlScore / psgCounts));


            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (CustomPsg psg : psgGroups) {
                sb.append(psg.psg).append("{{").append(psg.score/maxScore).append("}}").append(ellipsis);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private class CustomPsg {
            public String psg;
            public double score;
            public CustomPsg(String psg, double score) {
                this.psg = psg;
                this.score = score;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and with this extended code, i'm getting snippets and their scores in search results, as follows:

```
.....sions and other areas subject to its jurisdiction[22.847776]. [[22.847776]]{{0.954086}}

..... and the Trustee[19.287382]. [[19.287382]]{{0.805409}}
```

Number in **[ ]** indicates score of a single statement, number in **[[ ]]** indicates avg score (sum of all sentences' scores / sentence count in snippet) of the whole snippet (a snippet may contain multiple sentences), and number in **{{ }}** indicates snippet's relative score (against other snippet's avg scores).